# Fail to read configuration file from @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, gradle, annotations

I'm trying to apply the next annotation to a the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan({ "com.foo.*" })
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value = "file:${catalina.home}/conf/foo.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
})
```

but I'm getting the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to parse configuration class [com.company.config.CoreConfig];
>   nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [foo.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I've tried to look for this error on google and found many relevant things but nothing that could help me.

The file path is:

> /home/me/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/conf

Comment: have you read this document

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Comment: It isn't a compilation error... It is a runtime error which occurs during startup of your application.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, I updated in the question.

Comment: @RameshKhadka thanks for the docs, I've finished reading it now, but stil don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is of course the configuration class of the project. I didn't write it, I's an existing working project and I'm just trying to add the PropertySources annotation in order to read props from the config file.

Comment: @RameshKhadka I've also added all the relevant code for reading the file. I just didn't post it here because it's obvious that the problem is in the annotation and the code isn't executed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by removing this line:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties"),
```